# Zenoss 3 adding custom properties

Tags: zenoss

I could not find how to do it. The latest Zenoss 3 documentation http://community.zenoss.org/docs/DOC-6006 mentions about a section titled "Adding Custom Properties". But I could not find it. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to "Infrastructure", then under "Devices" and in the "Infrastructure" list click "Details".  The monitoring templates will appear and here you can edit the configuration properties, custom schema, etc...

Comment: Spot on! That's a difficult find for me.